# Tabularx environment problem

Tags: beamer, tabularx

I am running into a problem while using the following code and I have tried every means to diagnose the problem (ie: commenting the contents out), but I have not been successful at finding the bug.

The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
%\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=30]{Summary Statistics}          
    \vspace*{2em}          
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} 


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{10}{S[table-format=3.3]} @{}}
    \toprule   
\thead[lc]{Benchmark} & \thead{(1,1)} & {\thead{(2,1)}} & {\thead{(3,1)}} & {\thead{(4,1)}} & {\thead{(5,1)}} & {\thead{(6,1)}} \
    & {\thead{(7,1)}} & \thead{(8,1)} & {\thead{(9,1)}} & {\thead{(10,1)}} & {\thead{(11,1)}} & {\thead{(12,1)}} \\
    \midrule

(1,1) & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.09 & 0.00 \\


\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{frame}
```

The message I am getting is: "extra } or $", but I have checked everywhere and I don't see any problems. Hence, I would appreciate any help and advice.

Comment: Where is the compilable MWE?

Comment: Sorry edited to include all preambles

Comment: I don't care about your preamble at all. You are missing the document environment. It is important to limit the error to a minimum.

Comment: Your defintion of the `L` column is faulty. `X` columns want to get a width.

Comment: @Johannes_B Ah, I see, sorry that was an error on my part as I missed it when copying. I have made the correct changes to define the document environment. How should you propose that I make the changes to redefine the columns ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the objective is to make the width of the table equal to the width of the textblock, using a `tabular*` environment instead of a `tabularx` environment (with a single X-like column) seems preferable.

Incidentally, you may want to rethink using bold lettering for the header row. Sandwiching the header row between `\toprule` and `\midrule` is more than enough to give it all the visual prominence it requires; too much bold material quickly risks creating a vulgar look. The second table in the screenshot below demonstrates that (in my opinion) bold lettering is quite unnecessary.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=30]{Summary Statistics}          
\vspace*{2em}          
% Let LaTeX determine amount of intercolumn whitespace
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt} 

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{c}}
\toprule   
\textbf{Benchmark}& \textbf{(1,1)} 
& \textbf{(2,1)}  & \textbf{(3,1)} & \textbf{(4,1)} & \textbf{(5,1)}  
& \textbf{(6,1)}  & \textbf{(7,1)} & \textbf{(8,1)}  & \textbf{(9,1)} 
& \textbf{(10,1)} & \textbf{(11,1)} & \textbf{(12,1)} \\
\midrule
(1,1) & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.09 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular*} 

\vspace*{2cm}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l 
         @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{12}{c}}
\toprule   
{Benchmark}& (1,1) 
& (2,1)  & (3,1) & (4,1) & (5,1)  & (6,1) & (7,1) 
& (8,1)  & (9,1) & (10,1)& (11,1) & (12,1) \\
\midrule
(1,1) & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.09 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular*} 


\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

I use the package `rccol` which is easier to handle in this case. If you do not need three decimals then use `R[.]{1}{2}` instead

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand\MC[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\bfseries#1}}
\usepackage{rccol}

\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}[shrink=30]{Summary Statistics}                  
        \bigskip\noindent\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}
        \begin{tabular}{@{} l *{12}{R[.]{1}{3}} @{}}\toprule   
            Benchmark & \MC{(1,1)} & \MC{(2,1)} & \MC{(3,1)} & \MC{(4,1)} & \MC{(5,1)} & \MC{(6,1)} 
            & \MC{(7,1)} & \MC{(8,1)} & \MC{(9,1)} & \MC{(10,1)} & \MC{(11,1)} & \MC{(12,1)} \\\midrule             
            (1,1) & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.09 & 0.00 \\                        
            \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{frame}

 \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The actual error was missing multicolumn entries and declaring the wrong number of columns, however as the other answers have commented `tabularx` is the wrong environment to use for tables of numbers.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,multirow,tabularx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c}{#1}}
\newcommand\m[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\usepackage{siunitx}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[shrink=30]{Summary Statistics}          
    \vspace*{2em}          
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt} 


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L *{11}{S[table-format=3.3]} @{}}
    \toprule   
\m{\thead[lc]{Benchmark}} & \m{\thead{(1,1)}} & \m{\thead{(2,1)}} & \m{\thead{(3,1)}} & \m{\thead{(4,1)}} & \m{\thead{(5,1)}} & \m{\thead{(6,1)}} 
    & \m{\thead{(7,1)}} & \m{\thead{(8,1)}} & \m{\thead{(9,1)}} & \m{\thead{(10,1)}} & \m{\thead{(11,1)}} & \m{\thead{(12,1)}} \\
    \midrule
(1,1) & 0.00 & 0.01 & 0.02 & 0.02 & 0.03 & 0.03 & 0.05 & 0.02 & 0.01 & 0.01 & 0.09 & 0.00 \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabularx} 

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```